# I'm trying to use pyspark in jupyter lab but i this error is displayed: 'spark' is not defined

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-lab

I i'm currently working on jupyter lab and, for what i know, using a pyspark shell i should not define the SparkSession. So this is my code:

```
import pyspark 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
df = spark.read.csv('...'%path, sep=";", header=True)
df.limit(5).toPandas()
```

I'm trying to read the data from a csv file in the cluster but the following error is given:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-740a82943c15> in <module>
      1 path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
----> 2 df = spark.read.csv('file:///%s/../../big_data/BoardTracebility_filterdata_5/part*' class="ansi-blue-fg">%path, sep=";", header=True)
      3 df.limit(5).toPandas()

NameError: name 'spark' is not defined
```

There are multiple solutions to this error in stackOverflow but all of them are defining a spark session, which i should not define since i'm using a pyspark shell because it should be already initialized. How can i fix this problem without defining the spark session?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with Pyspark: Python can't find the variable called `spark`. Did you mean `pyspark.read.csv`?

Comment: no the command to be used is spark.read.csv. In other situations the code works but now i have this problem and i don't know why

Comment: I don't think this is the command to be used because Python can't find the variable called `spark`. `spark.read.csv` means "find the variable `spark`, get the value of its `read` attribute and then get this value's `csv` method", but this fails since `spark` doesn't exist. This isn't a Spark problem: you could've as well written `nonexistent_variable.read.csv`.

Comment: yes but, since i'm using a pyspark shell, the spark name should be identified as the SparkSession if i'm not wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end i solved the problem by installing another version of pyspark (version 2.3.2). The code worked without any change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first initialize the SparkSession and assign it to `spark` variable and then proceed with reading the CSV file.

Add the below line before `spark.read.csv` line, refer the below code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName().getOrCreate()
```

Without spark session you can't proceed.